# More efficent way of generating this random distribution?

Tags: c++, math, random

Is there a more efficent, possibly more mathematical and less algorithmic way of achieving a similar random number distribution to this?

```
unsigned int weighted_random_UINT()
{
    float r2 = 1;
    while(rand() % 4 != 0) // 3/4 chance
    {
        r2 *= fmod(
            ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)+1, // random float between 1 and 2
            (float)UINT_MAX
        );
    }
    return (unsigned int)r2 - 1;
}
```

Below is a less safe but more easily readable version of the inside of the while.

```
r2 *= ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)+1;
```

---

The distribution visualized:
[image: the distribution visualized]

---

Comparison between the smoother solution in the question (1st graph) and the faster solution in the best answer (2nd graph):
[comparison http://with-logic.co.uk/a/graph.png](http://with-logic.co.uk/a/graph.png)

Comment: and what's the expected distribution? just to verify that your code is correct..

Comment: Can you summarize the distribution?  That's a wierd one.  It should return 0 almost 50% of the time...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the distribution would be called.

Comment: The distribution is decreasing, 100000 random numbers are distributed like: `0=49998, 1=11425, 2=7380, 3=4376, 4=3435, 5=2487, 6=1872, 7=1635, 8=1314, 9=1054, >9=15024`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution Looks like an exponential distribution, but with a high exponent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't have to loop through it, but once is enough, like so:

```
unsigned int weighted_random_UINT()
{
    float r2 = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)+1; // random float between 1 and 2
    unsigned int k = 0;
    while(rand() % 4 != 0) // 3/4 chance
    {k = k < UINT_MAX ? k + 1: UINT_MAX;}
    return (unsigned int)fpow(r2,(float)k) - 1;
}
```

The first part is a geometric distribution, and the last one is an uniform distribution.
And you want `(1+U(0,1))^G(3/4)`.

It should be possible to find some faster way to find G(3/4) though.

**Edit:**
I found it on wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Related_distributions

```
G(p)=floor(ln(U)/ln(1-p))
```

Thus you want:

```
U^floor(ln(U)/ln(1-3/4))
```

Which should be just two calls to rand.

Comment: ty, having a look though the answer. I took out of the fmod part from the r2 *= line in you'r answer as doing it only once means I don't need it, at least I don't need it there.

Comment: Exactly right. But look at the updated answer for an even faster version.

Comment: I didn't understand the end of you'r answer, but it seems you'r verstion uses the power function to simulate multiplying by a typical number multiple times instead of actually multiplying and using a different number each time, as can be seen in this graph the result in less smooth but fine for my purpose and presumably faster, tyvm http://with-logic.co.uk/a/graph.png

Comment: That may be due to rounding, or maybe an imperfect psuedo-random algorithm. If you want something similar to what you have try e^U, which should be faster, and give less errors. You'd have to scale it for it to be exactly the same as yours though...

Comment: It's not due to rounding, mutiply by 1.2 then 1.7 then 1.3 for example is not the same as multiply by 1.4 (the average) three times, it is however good enough :¬) The algorithm is unlimited as to the maximum size so while e^U (not sure what 'e' and 'U' stand for) is a lot shorter than all the code listed above I don't think it's similar. Perhaps something like tan(random between 0 and 90) would work.

Comment: U is an uniform distribution between 0 and 1. r2 is U in my code. U^2 = U*U actually, although it's a little hard to prove. 0.5*0.5 is equally probable as 0.5^2 occurring, thus they are the same. This can be extended to (U+1) too.

Comment: note that in C++ `1-3/4` is 1.  You probably want `1-3.0/4` or `.25`